# Setup of Cyberark Conjur server

Tags: docker, cyber-ark

I've created a project in node.js to store and fetch credentials from cyberark conjur (using its REST-API)
But to test the application I'm stumbling to setup conjur server.

- Problem is server is running fine within docker container, but how to access it outside(host machine) (port mapping is not working)
- Or is there any conjur server hosted on Internet for public usage

All I want is to test API calls

Comment: Please share some info if you got any solution.

Answer (score 2):

As of writing this, the [Conjur Node.js API](https://github.com/conjurinc/api-node) is not currently actively being supported. Here are some suggestions for testing the API's.

Can I see the command you're using to start docker/docker-compose file?

**Method 1**

If you're using the setup from the [Conjur Quickstart Guide](https://www.conjur.org/get-started/quick-start/oss-environment/), your `docker-compose.yml` file should look something like:

```
...
conjur:
    image: cyberark/conjur
    container_name: conjur_server
    command: server
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres@database/postgres
      CONJUR_DATA_KEY:
      CONJUR_AUTHENTICATORS:
    depends_on:
    - database
    restart: on-failure

  proxy:
    image: nginx:1.13.6-alpine
    container_name: nginx_proxy
    ports:
      - "8443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./conf/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/:ro
      - ./conf/tls/:/etc/nginx/tls/:ro
    depends_on:
    - conjur
    - openssl
    restart: on-failure
...
```

This means Conjur is running behind an NGINX proxy to handle the SSL and does not have a port exposed to outside the Docker network it is running on. With this setup you can access the Conjur Server on `https://localhost:8443` on your local machine.

**Note:** You will need the SSL cert located in `./conf/tls/`. Since this is a demo environment, these are made readily available for testing like this.

**Method 2**

If you do not care about security and are just purely testing the REST API endpoints, you could always cut out the SSL and just modify the `docker-compose.yml` to expose the Conjur server's port to your local machine like this:

```
...
conjur:
    image: cyberark/conjur
    container_name: conjur_server
    command: server
    environment:
      DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres@database/postgres
      CONJUR_DATA_KEY:
      CONJUR_AUTHENTICATORS:
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    depends_on:
    - database
    restart: on-failure
```

Now you'll be able to talk to the Conjur Server on your local machine through `http://localhost:8080`.

For more info: [Networking in Docker Compose docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)